# Remove blank lines from the ends of a bunch of files

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a bunch of files with many lines in them, and usually one or two blank lines at the end.

I want to remove the blank lines at the end, while keeping all of the blank lines that may exist within the file.

I want to restrict the operation to the use of GNU utilities or similar, i.e. bash, sed, awk, cut, grep etc.

I know that I can easily remove *all* blank lines, with something like:

`sed '/^$/d'`

But I want to keep blank lines which exist prior to further content in the file.

File input might be as follows:

```
line1
line2

line4
line5
```

I'd want the output to look like:

```
line1
line2

line4
line5
```

All files are <100K, and we can make temporary copies.

Comment: Could you please explain why you downvoted the question.

Comment: are they huge files? can we make temporary copies?

Comment: small files (less than 100K), yes we can :)

Comment: Not my downvote, but we generally expect questions to show research effort as well as your best attempt at coding a solution. I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81685/how-to-remove-multiple-newlines-at-eof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n*$//; s/$/\n/' file
```

Second `S` command (`s/$/\n/`) appends again a newline to end of your file to be POSIX compilant.

Or shorter:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n*$/\n/' file
```

With Fela Maslen's comment to edit files in place (`-i`) and glob all elements in current directory (`*`):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n*$/\n/' -i *
```

Comment: You can use the -i switch to edit in place, and use * to glob all files in the current directory, i.e.: `perl -0777 -pe 's/\n*$/\n/' -i *`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` solution (Standard linux `gawk`). I enjoyed writing.

single line:

```
awk '/^\s*$/{s=s $0 ORS; next}{print s $0; s=""}' input.txt
```

using a readable script `script.awk`

```
    /^\s*$/{skippedLines = skippedLines $0 ORS; next}
    {print skippedLines $0; skippedLines= ""}
```

explanation:

```
/^\s*$/ {                   # for each empty line
    skippedLines = skippedLines $0 ORS; # pad string of newlines
    next;                   # skip to next input line
}
{                           # for each non empty line
    print skippedLines $0;  # print any skippedLines and current input line
    skippedLines= "";       # reset skippedLines
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If lines containing just space chars are to be considered empty:

```
$ tac file | awk 'NF{f=1}f' | tac
line1
line2

line4
line5
```

otherwise:

```
$ tac file | awk '/./{f=1}f' | tac
line1
line2

line4
line5
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/\S/{n;ba};$d;N;ba' file
```

If the current line contains a non-space character, print the current pattern space, fetch the next line and repeat. If the current line(s) is/are empty and it is the last line in the file, delete the pattern space, otherwise append the next line and repeat.