How to remove trailing empty lines in a txt file using python (or anything else)
I want to go from something like this
Some useful data to keep
More useful data to keep
<empty line to remove>

To something like this
Some useful data to keep
More useful data to keep

Using python is not important but preferred, anything other tools, software or languages will be useful, ~10000 files need to be processed. The files in question are label files for training a YOLO model. If the empty extra lines wont be a problem when training the model, please tell me.
The stuff I've seen removes empty lines in-between lines nothing about trailing lines. Also tried ones that remove trailing whitespaces, but those remove trailing whitespaces in a line that already has data, nothing about removing completely empty extra lines.

Not Python, but Perl/awk/sed solutions that may be much faster, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722547/remove-blank-lines-from-the-ends-of-a-bunch-of-files

Try the method rstrip() (see doc Python 2 and Python 3)
>>> 'test string\n'.rstrip()
'test string'

Python's rstrip() method strips all kinds of trailing whitespace by default, not just one newline as Perl does with chomp.
>>> 'test string \n \r\n\n\r \n\n'.rstrip()
'test string'

To strip only newlines:
>>> 'test string \n \r\n\n\r \n\n'.rstrip('\n')
'test string \n \r\n\n\r '

In addition to rstrip(), there are also the methods strip() and lstrip().
highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip) function to do this as follows:
filename = "test.txt"

with open(filename) as f_input:
    data = f_input.read().rstrip('\n')
    
with open(filename, 'w') as f_output:    
    f_output.write(data)

